# Unity Springjoint2d - how to put collider between anchors?

Tags: unity, 2d, collision-detection, physics

I want gameobjects to bounce off a line between 2 springjoint points. I placed boxcollider2d (with small Y scale) or edgecollider2d between two Joint points **and every frame put it in right place, set different x scale, and set different rotation**, but it doesn't work - other objects don't bounce on collision, they go through collider instead. I know that unity collisions work properly when objects move because of velocity instead of changing position every frame. Attaching collider to any of two objects connected by joint won't do what i want. Any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: It sounds like you know the answer: move the object with the physics engine, using Velocity or MovePosition, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your your answer! I find it sophiscated to change position precisely using velocity directly, and it turned out that MovePosition implementation causes joints (many connected together) to move faster and faster after multiple collisions, I also tried targetjoint2d, but that also doesn't fill my expectations, but I have finally done it

Answer (score 0):

Solution [very simple][after hours]: I added rigidbody2d to boxcollider object and set mass for highest possible, it turned out that when object is many times heavier than other, then other will be pushed out of it much harder, and collisions look normal (tested on slowly moving object, but works), there is no going through collider like when the mass is lower.

---

To make interaction between object colliding with mentioned boxcollider and objects connected with springjoint i wrote a script. (Useful when making spring joints bridge (that I m doing and didnt mention) and it should interact with heavy things driving through the bridge, change its shape depending on on which place of bridge the heavy thing is)
Finally good effect
Special thanks to DMGregory, the only person to comment till now!

Comment: This answer would be more useful to other readers if you included your script. Don't forget to mark the answer as Accepted if it worked for you.